# Omit part of an HTML while using PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to load part of a targeted URL ($url) into my HTML page, currently the $url page sends back a name, model, type and self recalculate tool - all of which live in a HTML TR tags.

Once I post my daily password from password.php than my users click on $url to get their daily inventory from it, again and i don't mean to be redundant, but the $url itself is provided to me by my clients and I don't want my users to be able to see all the links on that page - Only what pertain to their job.

Also rather than me creating password.php is there a way for me to "collect" this password from my daily outlook exchange email and post it to the header of the $url??

Many thx and I hope i was descriptive enough.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Post Password</title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <?php
            $password = "";
            ?>
            <form name="password" method="post" action="users.php">
              <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
            <tr>
              <td>Paste the Daily Password</td>
              <td><input type="text" maxlength=7 name="password"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
            </tr>
              </table>
                </form>

    </body>
</html>




<html>
    <head>
        <title>First Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <?php 

            $url_append = "?secret=";
            //$psk = $password;
            $linktext = "Click here to get a Pre Shared Key";
            $password = $_POST["password"];


            $url = "http://example.subexample.xx.com/";
            $url .= $url_append;
            $url .= $password;
            $final_url = $url;
            // end base users
            ?>

<!--I took this form below from the URL that my client host-->
<!--His url have way more input than all_products-->
<!-- but that's the only one that I want to echo for my employees to use -->
<form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($final_url);?>">
              <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
            <tr>
              <td>Main Inventory</td>
              <td><input type="text" maxlength=7 name="all_products"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
            </tr>
              </table>
                </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For sending POST through header take a look at [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/http-headers-for-dummies--net-8039).

As for the omitting the parts of html, you can use alternative syntax like this

```
<?php if ($a == 5): ?>
<p>This will be omitted if condition is not true</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Similar can be used for `for` loop.

[Read more](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) on alternative syntax.

Comment: Works like a charm! thanks a million - Here's another 2 questions that are puzzling me. is there a PHP function that let me "tap" into my own email to retrieve the daily inventory password?

Comment: you'll have to look at yours mail API if it has one.